# comparing two strings with 'is' -- not performing as expected

Tags: python, string-comparison, string-literals

I'm attempting to compare two strings with **is**. One string is returned by a function, and the other is just declared in the comparison. **is** tests for object identity, but according to [this page](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pythontutorial/keywords/), it also works with two identical strings because of Python's memory optimization. But, the following doesn't work:

```
def uSplit(ustring):
        #return user minus host
        return ustring.split('!',1)[0]

user = uSplit('theuser!host')
print type(user)
print user
if user is 'theuser':
    print 'ok'
else:
    print 'failed'

user = 'theuser'

if user is 'theuser':
    print 'ok'
```

The output:

```
type 'str'
theuser
failed
ok
```

I'm guessing the reason for this is a string returned by a function is a different "type" of string than a string literal. Is there anyway to get a function to return a string literal? I know I could use **==**, but I'm just curious.

Comment: the `is` keyword is for checking identity, not equality, so it is the wrong tool for the job anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site you quote says this:

> If two string literals are equal, they have been put to same memory location.

But

```
uSplit('theuser!host')
```

is not a string literal -- it's the result of an operation on the literal `'theuser!host'`.

Anyway, you usually shouldn't check for string equality using `is`, because this memory optimization in any case is just an implementation detail you shouldn't rely on.

---

Also, You should use `is` for things like `is None`.  Use it for checking to see if two objects -- of classes that you designed -- are the same instance.  You can't easily use it for strings or numbers because the rules for creation of those built-in classes are complex.  Some strings are interned.  Some numbers, similarly, are interned.

Comment: The rules for interning are indeed strange. If uSplit returned a string with 2 or less characters, the 'is' comparison works. I guess it's safest to stick to using ==.

Comment: It's not a "safest".  It's a matter of definition.  Strings are not defined as always interned.  Some are, but there's no explicit guarantee, so you simply can't use `is` with strings.  It's not safety, so much as a matter of definition.

Comment: Exactly. "is" has its purpose, "==" has its purpose. Different purposes.

Answer (score 4):

That page you quoted says "If two string **literals** are equal, they have been put to same memory location" (emphasis mine). Python interns literal strings, but strings that are returned from some arbitrary function are separate objects. The `is` operator can be thought of as a pointer comparison, so two different objects will not compare as identical (even if they contain the same characters, ie. they are equal).

Comment: In the larger scheme of things, it's rare that ANY language makes strong guarantees about memory on a managed-memory system (garbage collected or reference-counting with cycle detection).  Even when they do it's not generally good to rely on it because the guarantee might disappear in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

What you have run into is the fact that Python does not always intern all of its strings. More detail here:

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2009-July/070157.html