# Python string with space and without space at the end and immutability

Tags: python, string, immutability, cpython, python-internals

I learnt that in some immutable classes, `__new__` may return an existing instance - this is what the `int`, `str` and `tuple` types sometimes do for small values.

But why do the following two snippets differ in the behavior?

With a space at the end:

```
>>> a = 'string '
>>> b = 'string '
>>> a is b
False
```

Without a space:

```
>>> c = 'string'
>>> d = 'string'
>>> c is d
True
```

Why does the space bring the difference?

Comment: Sorry. Not reproducible :)

Comment: Are you doing in python interactive shell or scrip.py, in script.py it return same result, so i thought something is going on while compiling the code. Because in iteractive shell every line is compiled when we press enter.

Comment: also, `a='st '; b='st '; a is b` gives `True`

Comment: Keyword: may. `__new__` _may_ return a cached reference to an existing object with the same value. It is not guaranteed to do so. (I do reproduce this behavior on CPython 3.2.3 64bit, though.)

Comment: and make them in a function in multi-lines still prints `True`

Comment: @thefourtheye Reproducible on my end. I'm using the python 3 interpreter.

Comment: Do you know what the word "may" means in this context?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a quirk of how the CPython implementation chooses to cache string literals. String literals with the same contents may refer to the same string object, but they don't have to. `'string'` happens to be automatically interned when `'string '` isn't because `'string'` contains only characters allowed in a Python identifier. I have no idea *why* that's the criterion they chose, but it is. The behavior may be different in different Python versions or implementations.

From the CPython 2.7 source code, [`stringobject.h`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/23a760bdd4b1/Include/stringobject.h#l28), line 28:

> Interning strings (ob_sstate) tries to ensure that only one string 
>   object with a given value exists, so equality tests can be one pointer
>   comparison.  This is generally restricted to strings that "look like" 
>   Python identifiers, although the intern() builtin can be used to force
>   interning of any string.

You can see the code that does this in [`Objects/codeobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/codeobject.c#l71):

```
/* Intern selected string constants */
for (i = PyTuple_Size(consts); --i >= 0; ) {
    PyObject *v = PyTuple_GetItem(consts, i);
    if (!PyString_Check(v))
        continue;
    if (!all_name_chars((unsigned char *)PyString_AS_STRING(v)))
        continue;
    PyString_InternInPlace(&PyTuple_GET_ITEM(consts, i));
}
```

Also, note that interning is a separate process from the merging of string literals by the Python bytecode compiler. If you let the compiler compile the `a` and `b` assignments together, e.g. by placing them in a module or an `if True:`, you would find that `a` and `b` would be the same string.

Comment: I remember reading about this somewhere. Do you have a link ready, by chance?

Comment: Ya i would like to see some implementation details to make me clearly understood.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a link. The closest I have is a [forum discussion](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/803532-python-string-comparison-oddity) between people I don't know and can't trust.

Comment: @yopy: I found a source code link, though not the actual part of the source code that handles the job.

Answer (score 5):

This behavior is not consistent, and as others have mentioned depends on the variant of Python being executed.  For a deeper discussion, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning).

If you want to make *sure* that the same object is being used you can force the interning of strings by the appropriately named `intern`:

> intern(...)
>       intern(string) -> string
>
> ```
> ``Intern'' the given string.  This enters the string in the (global)
> table of interned strings whose purpose is to speed up dictionary lookups.
> Return the string itself or the previously interned string object with the
> same value.
> ```

```
>>> a = 'string '
>>> b = 'string '
>>> id(a) == id(b)
False
>>> a = intern('string ')
>>> b = intern('string ')
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True
```

Note in Python3, you have to explicitly import intern `from sys import intern`.

Comment: thanks for the information, But i was looking for the reason why it behaves differently.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning) for more.

Comment: In Python 3, `intern` is now within the `sys` module.